# maximum modulus little doubt

Tags: complex-analysis

In the maximum modulus therem we have two sets
$E_1=\{z \in E:|f(z)|<M\} \quad E_2=\{z \in E:|f(z)|=M\}$ I know that the set $E_1$ is open because pre image of an open set. But should't be also $E_2$ closed because pre image of only a point ?

Comment: $E_2$ is the pre-image of a circle.